# how to convert an alphanumeric string into time formatting?

Tags: python, string, time

I've got some reaction times as alphanumeric strings (e.g. '2m34s235', '23s98'). I want to convert these strings into the traditional time formatting (e.g.'00:02:34.235', '00:00;23.98'). My program does the job well when the string contains minutes, seconds and ms. However, there are situations in which my string contains only the minutes and the ms numbers, but not the seconds (e.g. '1m567'). So, for these cases, my output is not what I want. A good output for this situation would be 00:01:00,567').  Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks!

My code so far is below:

```
list_of_strings= ['6m874','1m767','7m4s123','5s678','3m5s,429','7m45s,346','4m2s,345','23s,98', '1s,962', '5s,337']


new_list = [s.replace("s", "") for s in list_of_strings]
new_l=[s.replace(",", ".") for s in new_list]
tm=[]

for i in new_l:
    if 'm' and 's' in i:
        c='00:0'+str(i)
        c1=c.replace('m',':')
        tm.append(c1)
    elif 'm' in i:
        e=c='00:0'+str(i)
        e1=e.replace('m',':00,')
        tm.append(e1)
    elif float(i) < 10:
        a='00:00:0' + str(i)
        tm.append(a)
    else:
        b='00:00:' + str(i)
        tm.append(b)


for x in tm:
    print(x)
```

the output  I got for this sample was:

00:06:00,874 -
00:01:00,767 -
00:07:00,4123 -
00:00:5678 -
00:03:00,5.429 -
00:07:00,45.346 -
00:04:00,2.345 -
00:00:23.98 -
00:00:01.962 -
00:00:05.337 -

Output I want is:

00:06:00.874 -
00:01:00.767 -
00:07:04.123 -
00:00:05.678 -
00:03:05.429 -
00:07:45.346 -
00:04:2.345 -
00:00:23.98 -
00:00:01.962 -
00:00:05.337 -

Comment: If you managed to write the code this far, what was preventing you from writing more code to cover additional cases?

Comment: How should your code know if `1m1` means 1 minute and 1 second or 1 minute and 1 millisecond?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think the seconds are always followed by `s`.

Comment: Why do you test if `s` is contained in a string of you have removed `s` from the string before?

Comment: unless i am missing something this is a very simple fix.  Look at your second `replace` statement.  why do you have a comma after the `:00`?  Change that to a period. Output looks correct to me after that.  There are probably other issues as noted in other comments, but that at least clears the question at hand

Comment: Why are there commas in some of the strings?

Comment: @James oh I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fix for the code. First of all, I removed the comma (,) from the strings. Secondly, going from minutes, over seconds, and finally to ms. Also, separated checks for 'm' and 's'. In addition to that, I added a check if the number of minutes and seconds is less than 10, in which case I'd add a 0 in front of it, otherwise, just take the number.

This gives the result you wanted, though in your case, I'd add a check for milliseconds as well so that all ms results are with 3 characters (098 instead of 98)

list_of_strings= ['6m874','1m767','7m4s123','5s678','3m5s,429','7m45s,346','4m2s,345','23s,98', '1s,962', '5s,337']

```
new_list = [s.replace(",", "") for s in list_of_strings]
tm=[]

for v in new_list:
    c = '00:'
    l = v.split('m')
    if len(l) > 1:
        if int(l[0]) < 10:
            tmp = f'0{int(l[0])}:'
        else:
            tmp = f'0{int(l[0])}:'
        vs = l[1]
    else:
        vs = l[0]
        tmp = '00:'
    c = c + tmp

    l = vs.split('s')
    if len(l) > 1:
        if int(l[0]) < 10:
            tmp = f'0{int(l[0])}.{l[1]}'
        else:
            tmp = f'{int(l[0])}.{l[1]}'
    else:
        if 's' in vs:
            if int(l[0]) < 10:
                tmp = f'0{int(l[0])}.000'
            else:
                tmp = f'{int(l[0])}.000'
        else:
            tmp = f'00.{int(l[0])}'
    c = c + tmp

    tm.append(c)

for x in tm:
    print(x)
```